# Use KeysConverter in console application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a Key int value into it's Char form with KeysConverter, this seems to work in a windows forms C# application but not in console app. can i add an assembly reference to make it recognised ?

http://prntscr.com/n6whlu

sorry if this is obvious, I'm not familiar with the specific differences between windows forms and console.

thank you.

-Dylan

Comment: Please post error messages and code as text for better searchability and reproducability.

Comment: You could import System.Windows.Forms as reference. What exactly are you trying to do though? seems like there's probably an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`KeysConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keysconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) is part of Windows Forms.

So you need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to your project and a `using System.Windows.Forms;` to your code file.